# Swift unwrapping Optional value by "?" and "!"

Tags: swift, option-type

What are the differences when i unwrap Optional value by `?` and `!`

If there is Class name A and there is a property name proA

Then if i make an instance like this

```
var a:A? = A()
a?.proA
a!.proA
```

I can approach property 'proA' two ways above. I know I cannot get value if I use `a.proA` because `a` is a Optional Type.

Also, I know `a!.proA` can get value because it unwrap the value in force

And what is `a?.proA`?

What are the differences between `a?.proA` and `a!.proA`

Comment: `a?`  is calling proA so that may be `a` is nil, here we notify to the compiler by `?` for the `a`. If the compiler will get nil it goes silently without crashing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated, `!` forcefully unwraps the optional.

```
  var a: A? = A()
  a!.prop
```

However, what happens if the optional was never assigned a value, which means it's `nil`?

```
  var a: A?;
  a!.pop
```

You get a Swift runtime error (think of it as the equivalent of a null pointer exception in other languages e.g. Java).

On the other hand, if you use `?`, you can take advantage of optional chaining. This allows you to gracefully traverse optional properties without fear of causing a runtime error. If some intermediate property along the chain is `nil`, the whole expression will return `nil`.

```
 var a: A?;
 a?.pop //returns nil, no runtime error
```

Comment: Oh...!! then if i use ? to unwrap the optional value, it's more safe than !. Thanks!